# Canvas Resizing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas that dynamically changes size on user input i.e. whenever he types in input text box. It works fine if the user inputs a new size greater than the current one but if i try to shrink it the canvas size the previous value persists... how can i do  this without refreshing the page?
Here's the code:

```
<p style="line-height: 18px; font-size:18px;  font-family: times;">
<br>
<div id = "div1">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Clickme</button>
<input type= "number" id ="tx1">
<input type= "number" id ="tx2">
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var node = document.getElementById("div1"); 
        var kid1 = document.createElement("p"); 
        var kid2 = document.createTextNode("hey"); 
        var kid3 = document.createElement("span"); 
        node.appendChild(kid1); 
        node.appendChild(kid2); 
        node.appendChild(kid3); 
    }
    window.onkeyup = function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        var t1=document.getElementById('tx1').value;
        var t2=document.getElementById('tx2').value;
        console.log(t1);
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, t1, t2);
};
</script>
```

Comment: it is because you never resize the canvas, you redraw on top of it
so when you reduce the size what was draw before is still there. Maybe you could fill it with white before redrawing that would clean it up

Comment: @jonatjano thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a [clearRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) in your code

```
window.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var t1=document.getElementById('tx1').value;
    var t2=document.getElementById('tx2').value;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(10,10,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, t1, t2);
    };
```